# Windows Ubuntu dual boot - Windows boot problem after updates

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

My Windows - Ubuntu dual boot system was working perfect for up to 6 months. After Windows updates, Windows can't boot. I have tried several things but nothing seems to work. You can find a Boot Repair report about my system [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15892965/)

Is there any way to get my Windows back?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into a windows RecoveryCD/Installation Disk, click on Repair, then click on Advance/Other options, select CMD Prompt as the recovery option, then run the following.

- bootrec.exe /fixboot
- bootrec.exe /fixmbr

Once you have done so, restart your computer and it should boot into windows automatically.

From there you will need to boot into your Ubuntu LiveCD and run boot-repair to repair grub back to it's normal state.

Comment: Hi @Feg, I have already tried this but nothing changed. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Odd, can't seem to think of anything else to do then as that's usually all it required. (I didn't use dual-boot for mcuh nor very long). Can you see the partitions in gparted?

Comment: it looked odd to me too. I could see all the partitions.